# SharePoint Framework (SPFx) information questions

Tags: sharepoint-framework, nodejs

I have to present the SharePoint Framework(SPFx) to colleagues but I don't find answer to all my questions.

I red main interests of SPFx are :

- improve the user experience
- open the door to open source development tools
- be more efficient than add-in, because iFrame are considered "slow"

Am I right ? And are there other points ?

In the Microsoft tutorial which details how create his first web part using SPFx, they use NodeJS. I understood, NodeJS is used to execute javascript code of my web part. Can you tell me more of the role of NodeJS in SPFx web parts development ? Does it interact with SharePoint server ?

Is the SPFx usefull to create only web parts ?

If I understood well the interest of the framework, it is not a suitable way to create a little "application" which allows to create subsites or other. Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The points you mentioned are few advantages out of all. You can read the [Key Features](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

The **Node.Js** is a cross-platform JavaScript runtime engine which plays the same role as .Net CLR in the .Net Applications. It is not going to interact with SharePoint server.

The first release of the SharePoint Framework will contain support for client-side web parts.

[SharePoint Framework Roadmap](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/roadmap)

You can also provision SharePoint assets as part of the SharePoint Framework solution.

[How To: Provision SharePoint assets](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package)

Answer (score 1):

[Please go through this article](https://technovert.com/evolution-of-sharepoint-from-server-side-to-client-side-2/). This article discuss some advantages and disadvantages about SPFx which can help you.

Overall the article discuss following advantage of SPFx:

1. Complete Client Side.
2. Fast, Lightweight and Responsive.
3. Run on User Context
4. Remote Development